# How do I dynamically add a new Panel to a Ext.tab.Panel?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'd like to dynamically add a new Panel or Container to an Ext.tab.Panel. I tried code like this:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Container');
panel.title = 'From Code';
panel.iconCls = 'home';
panel.styleHtmlContent = true;
panel.html = 'Hello from Code';

tabPanel.add(panel);
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration
```

I can add a new panel or container using the object literal style, but how do I do it when I construct a new object by hand? The Ext.Container class doesn't have a title property itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify iconCls and title configuration in Panel or Container when you adding to tabPanel

You did that but, i think the problem is the way you creating Container and setting iconCls, title configuration.

```
  var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
       title: 'From Code', 
       iconCls: 'home', 
       html : 'Hello from Code'
  });



 var tab = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});

 tab.add(panel);
```